# PowerShell command Set-WinUILanguageOverride: no effects

Tags: powershell, command

I run the command [Set-WinUILanguageOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride?view=win10-ps) -Language en-GB, but it seems that nothing happens. My Windows UI language is italian and remains italian also after I run the above command. How can I see the effect of the command?

Comment: How do you know that nothing has happened.  Can you provide an example of where Powershell's responses were unexpected?

Comment: Hello @WalterMitty the command should change the windows UI language, but the language of the settings for example remains in italian. Did i misunderstood the meaning of the command? Or maybe it's needed a reboot?

Comment: Yes I believe a logoff and logon are required for the changes to take effect.  See the help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuilanguageoverride?view=win10-ps

Comment: is German part of the LanguageList? you may have to add it: `Get-WinUserLanguageList`

Comment: Hi @WalterMitty I did a reboot, but the result is the same. Can you help me to run the right command please?

Comment: Not sure.  What does Get-host show you?

Comment: A logoff/reboot is definitely required. If the language pack for the specified culture isn't installed, `Set-WinUILanguageOverride` quietly fails, however. That said, in the case of `en-GB` I would expect it to _fall back_ to `en-US`, which I would expect to ship with Windows itself.